# Finding a distribution with a given correlation to a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

Below is my attempt to solve a problem which I believe has a solution. My work shows there is no solution. I believe I did something wrong. It could be related to the algebra.

Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ independent normally distributed random variables with a mean of $0$ and a standard deviation
of $1$. Let $K$ be a positive real number. Let $Z = Y + KX$ such that the correlation of $X$ and $Z$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. Find $K$.
Answer:
If we select $K = 0$ then we get a correlation of $0$. If we select $K$ to be a very large number
then the correlation will be close to $1$.
\begin{align*}
\rho &= \frac{1}{2} \\
u_x &= 0 \\
u_y &= 0 \\
u_z &= u_y + K(u_y) = 0 + K(0) = 0 \\
\sigma_x &= 1 \\
\sigma_y &= 1 \\
\sigma_z^2 &= \sigma_y^2 + K^2 \sigma_x^2 + K(\sigma_{xy}) \\
\sigma_{xy} &= 0 \\
\sigma_z^2 &= 1^2 + K^2 1^2 + K(0) = K^2 + 1 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{xz} &= E(XZ) - E(X)E(Z) \\
E(X) &= 0 \\
\sigma_{xz} &= E(XZ) - (0)E(Z) = E(XZ) \\
E(XZ) &= E( X(Y+KX)) = E(XY + KX^2) = E(XY) + KE(X^2) \\
E(X^2) &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to find $E(XY)$.
\begin{align*}
E(XY) &= E(X) E(Y) = 0(0) \\
E(XY) &= 0 \\
E(XZ) &= 0 + K(1) = K \\
\sigma_{xz} &= K \\
\rho_{xz} &= \frac{\sigma_x \sigma_z }{\sigma_{xz}} \\
\frac{1}{2} &= \frac{ \sqrt{K^2+1} }{K} \\
\frac{K}{2} &= \sqrt{K^2+1} \\
\frac{K^2}{4} &= K^2 + 1 \\
\frac{-3K^2}{4} &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
This equation has no real roots.

Comment: Your correlation formula is inverse. Correlation is equal to covariance divided by product of standard deviations. Fix that and you get $K=1/\sqrt{3}$ and $K=-1/\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the correlation is incorrect (you mixed the numerator with the denominator). The corrected one is below (as already stated in the comments).

$$\rho_{xz}=\frac{\sigma_{xz}}{\sigma_x\sigma_z}$$

It can help to check your assumptions in cases like this, for example your claim that 'if $K$ is very large the correlation approaches $1$' does not hold with $\frac{\sqrt{K^2+1}}{K}$.

Answer (score 0):

$Cov(X,Z)=E(XZ)=E(X(Y+kX))=kE(X^2)+E(X)E(Y)=k,Var(Z)=1+k^2.$ So we want $1/2=cor(X,Z)=\frac{cov(X,Z)}{\sqrt{var(X)var(Z)}}=k/\sqrt{1+k^2}.$ So, $k=1/\sqrt 3$ should work.